# Macro definition that matches two strings

Tags: c++, macros, arguments, c-preprocessor, matching

I would like to define an expression in C++ with macros and I am having quite a bit of trouble.

- The expression is :

  **MATCH** string **WITH** other_string

where string and other_string do not require **" "**

For example: **MATCH r1 WITH string1** is the result i desire.

The purpose of this macro would be to check if r1 string matches with r2.

(I already have the code for the matching)

- UPDATE

I would like to call **MATCH hello WITH hi**

in my main function

```
int main(){ 

    MATCH hello WITH hi

}
```

and call my function from this macro to compare them. **Both hello and hi are unquoted arguments and must be treated as variable names

Comment: I think its quite clear in my example that there are no "" in hello and hi.
The only problem is how am i going to define something like this in order to be valid.
I want to treat unquoted arguments as variable names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always dubious to use macros to make your code look like a different language. It is probably better to consider using a separate parser for your "meta-language" that generates the C++ code for you.

In this case, since C++ syntax requires some way to indicate the end of a statement (close braces or semi-colon) you are in kind of a jam.

Consider your example:

```
int main () { MATCH hello WITH hi }
```

Since `hi` is the last token before the end of `main`, there is no chance to fix-up the syntax to match C++ requirements.

#### You can't do what you want, so you have to do something different

If you really intend to embed this syntax into your C++ code, you need sentinel tokens to allow you to fix-up the syntax. My proposed syntax is:

```
int main () {
BEGIN_MATCHING
MATCH hello WITH hi
MATCH hello WITH hi
END_MATCHING
};
```

If this syntax is acceptable, then you can use the following macros.

```
#define BEGIN_MATCHING ((void)0
#define MATCH ); my_function(
#define WITH ,
#define END_MATCHING );
```

This will cause the code in the proposed syntax example to expand to:

```
int main () {
((void)0
); my_function( hello , hi
); my_function( hello , hi
);
}
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/FH2VOL)

Comment: Thanks a lot, i kinda modified the code and made it work.
Thanks again :)

Comment: You're welcome. As you appear new to the site, I recommend you go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

Simply stringify your arguments with `#`, something like:

```
#define MATCH_WITH(str1, str2) MATCH #str1 WITH #str2
```

That way:

```
MATCH_WITH(testing, testing)
```

becomes:

```
MATCH "testing" WITH "testing"
```

Comment: I think that is as close as you can get, but it doesn't match the OPs required syntax, and it fails if str1 or str2 contain commas

Comment: i dont really want to achieve this result.I mean that i would like to call

MATCH hello WITH hi  
 in my main function

int main(){
MATCH hello WITH hi
}


and call my function to compare them.
Both hello and hi must not require ""